# in webview, javascript module is not working..?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webview, module, android-webview

I tested lots of way to figure out why my javascript is not working :(
my guess is... javascript module is not working with webview. is it true? or is there any way to use javascript module?

any guess and answers would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

## condition

I am using...

- android
- javascript
- webpack

When webview is opened, I want the `initialFucntion` to be fired by itself.

```kotlin
// kotlin
Handler().post {
    web_view_event.loadUrl("javascript:initialFunction('${userId}')")
}
```

this following code is working fine obviously.

```html
// html codes...
<script>
  function initialFucntion(userId){
    alert(userId)
  }
</script>
```

but...this following code is not working :(

```html
// html code ...
  <script src='test.js'></script>
<body>....
```

```js
// test.js 
  function initialFucntion(userId){
    alert(userId)
  }
```

What shall I do? What did I miss? Any advice is welcome.
I have to use javascript module :/ since there's lots of code line more than this sample codes..

#### webpack code

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/test.js', './src/main.css'],
    infomation: ['./src/infomation.css'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `빌드 날짜: ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      excludeChunks: ['infomation'],
      template: './src/index.html',
      minify:
        mode === 'production'
          ? {
              collapseWhitespace: true, // 빈칸 제거
              removeComments: true, // 주석 제거
            }
          : false,
      hash: mode === 'production',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'infomation.html',
      template: './src/infomation.html',
      chunks: ['infomation'],
      minify:
        mode === 'production'
          ? {
              collapseWhitespace: true, // 빈칸 제거
              removeComments: true, // 주석 제거
            }
          : false,
      hash: mode === 'production',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: `[name].css` }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes. I solved it. I assumed this as totally wrong direction. it was not about module but async problem. the kotlin(the initialFunction) should be fired after when javascript is fully loaded, but it did fired while javascript is loading, even before the initialFunction is initialized. so here is how I solve ⇒ when window.onload(()⇒

Comment: so here is how I solve ⇒ when `window.onload`, call the function initialized in kotiln to clear javascript is ready to go. after that fire the `initialFunction` which is designed to be fired when web-view is opened. that's it!

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out. I suggest add this as answer and accept as the correct answer.